# Rails - form_for doesn't send all elements of the form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, checkbox, form-for

I have this header of the form:

```
= form_for @item
  ...
  = check_box_tag 'post_to[]', p['id']
```

And in the form are added yet checkboxes. The values of these checkboxes will be stored in a different table than in the **items**.
The problem is, that when I send the form, the data from checkboxes are not sent.

How is that possible and how to make them "sendable"?

Thanks

Comment: If you check your development log can you see all the parameters being properly sent in the POST?

Comment: After submiting your form, you should be able to access to `params[:post_to]` which would be an array, but to have any value in this, you must check at least one checkbox

Comment: That's the thing - there's missing this parameter. I have checked several checkboxes.

Comment: Ok, sorry - I restarted server and now is everything working properly.

Comment: Further reading: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-check_box-label-Gotcha